# Union All returns value which has no record in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display **Resubmission** and **First Submission** (Both are Claim types) sepeartely based on the value of the related table.

So i have used the below query to get both the record seperately.

```
SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID), count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
       'Resubmission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
INNER JOIN Resubmission r ON r.ClaimID = c.ClaimPKID WHERE h.HeaderType=2 

UNION ALL 

SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID), count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
      'First Submission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
WHERE ClaimPKID NOT IN 
         ( SELECT ClaimID FROM Resubmission GROUP BY ClaimID ) AND HeaderType=2
```

In above query i have used `UNION ALL` to get datas from **Claim** table. If **Claim** Table primary key is used as a foreign key in **Resubmission** Table then it is a Resubmission Claim type and If it's not used in Resubmission table then it is First Submission.

My problem is Eventhough there's no record in table for the specific select query it returns Null value with Mentioning of Claim Type. Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) is worng,  ROUND(SUM(coalesce(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) is right

Comment: Ok thanks...but that is not an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
select * 
from
(SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID) claimid, count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
       'Resubmission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
INNER JOIN Resubmission r ON r.ClaimID = c.ClaimPKID WHERE h.HeaderType=2 

UNION ALL 

SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID), count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
      'First Submission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
WHERE ClaimPKID NOT IN 
         ( SELECT ClaimID FROM Resubmission GROUP BY ClaimID ) AND HeaderType=2) claims
where claims.claims <> 0
```

Comment: It might be helpful to describe how that solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation without Group By *always* returns a row, even when there's no data. To avoid this you can simply add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0`:

```
SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID), count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
       'Resubmission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
INNER JOIN Resubmission r ON r.ClaimID = c.ClaimPKID WHERE h.HeaderType=2 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0

UNION ALL 

SELECT ROUND(coalesce(SUM(c.ClaimNet), 0), 2) as net, 
       MAX(c.ClaimID), count(c.ClaimID) as claims, 
       MAX(h.TransactionDate) as TransactionDate, 
      'First Submission' AS 'Claim Type' 
FROM Claim c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimHeader h on h.HeaderID = c.HeaderPKID 
WHERE ClaimPKID NOT IN 
         ( SELECT ClaimID FROM Resubmission GROUP BY ClaimID ) AND HeaderType=2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```